# Get SelectedDataKey in RowDataBound

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, rowdatabound

this code is returning a NullReferenceException since the SelectedDataKey is not selected yet. How can I check if the the DataKey is selected or not..

```
    protected void grdRoles_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
    {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
       { 
          CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkRole"); 
          int rolecode = Convert.ToInt32(this.grdRoles.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value);
          BusinessLayer.Customers checkRole = new BusinessLayer.Customers();                   

         bool check = checkRole.CheckRoles(this.grdCustomers.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString(), rolecode); //this is triggering the nullReferenceException
         if (check)
         {
           chk.Checked = true;
         }                   
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use a different event. the databound event is for wiring the data the view. you are looking for an event to use the data after it's bound. most likely the [SelectedIndexChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) events