# Getting row index of checked row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to do when the `checkbox` column in my `gridview` is marked, I get the row index. My `gridview` is in a repeater and when I setup the `gridview`, I put a `DataKeyNames`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="pBody1" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBodyText1" runat="server" />
                            <!-- Grid view to show products based on each category -->
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="998px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" DataKeyNames="id">
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCheckRow" runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="600px" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="categoryName" HeaderText="Category" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbQuantity" runat="server" Width="60" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "inventoryQuantity") %>'/>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe1" runat="server" TargetControlID="pBody1" CollapseControlID="pHeader1"
                            ExpandControlID="pHeader1" Collapsed="true" ImageControlID="imgArrows1"
                            CollapsedImage="~/Images/downarrow.jpg"
                            ExpandedImage="~/Images/uparrow.jpg" TextLabelID="lblHeaderText1" CollapsedText="Show"
                            ExpandedText="Hide" CollapsedSize="0"
                            ScrollContents="false">
                        </asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbnConfirm" runat="server" class="btn dark" style="float: right" OnClick="lbnConfirm_Click">Confirm</asp:LinkButton>
```

When my `lbnConfirm` is `onclick`, I perform this to get the row index and store them into a list:

```
 protected void lbnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)Repeater1.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                GridViewRow row = gv.SelectedRow;
                string prodID = this.gv.DataKeys[row].Value.ToString();
                List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUList = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
                //Store the prodIDs into list
            }

        }
    }
```

When I run the page, it told me `object reference is not set to an instance` at this line:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
```

Also the `gv` of this line:

```
string prodID = this.gv.DataKeys[row].Value.ToString();
```

told me that the `gv` does not contain a definition of missing reference. I thought I declared at the code above?

Edited Portion:

```
       protected void lbnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
                GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
                foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                    if (cb.Checked)
                    {
                        string prodID = gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                        tempList.Add(prodID);
                        for (int count = 0; count < tempList.Count; count++)
                        {
                            lblTest.Text = tempList[count] + ",";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is right, however you need to consider few more things:

1. You have to loop through the `Repeater`'s items and find the `Panel` in
   each item.
2. You have to find the `GridView` inside the `Panel`, not in the `Repeater`.
3. You have to find the `DataKey` Value by `RowIndex`, not by row.

**EDIT :** To test, add a Label outside the repeater:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Also change the code to display Id in the label.

After rewriting `lbnConfirm_Click()` method, it should look like below:

```
protected void lbnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;

            GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                if (cb.Checked)
                {
                    //GridViewRow row = gv.SelectedRow;
                    string prodID =  gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                    List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUList = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
                    //Store the prodIDs into list
                    tempList.Add(prodID);                        
                }

            }
        }
    }  

    lblTest.Text = string.Join(",", tempList);       
}
```

The code above worked fine in my test! Only you have to be careful not to rebind the repeater at postback in Page_Load().

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have added these codes to test whether the prodID getting is correct or not (check the edited portion again, sorry). However, no matter I checked on which products, it just keep returning me a weird value as in I have no idea where the value comes from.

Comment: Oh ya, I forgot to concatenate the prodID and that's why it keeps returning one value instead of a list. Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, it keeps looping the record over and over again. Let's say I got product 1,2,6,7 checked. It returns me 1,1,2,1,2,6,1,2,6,7. I guess at the first check, it returns me 1. At the second check, it returns me 1,2 and so on. I guess because I am using repeater and collapsible panel extender and that's why it keep looping over and over again. Is there any ways to fix this?

Comment: @Gwen - I think your test has some issues, you should not loop through the list inside loops. I have added test code for this which worked for me. Can you please check?

Comment: @afzaluluh Oh I see. I put the for-loop at the wrong place. So basically if I wanted to loop thru the list to get product details of each prodID, I should replace the lblTest.Text with for-loop?

Comment: Also for each row which has been checked, I also need to get the user input for textbox which store the quantity. So inside the if statement of cb.Checked, I put this: TextBox tbQuantity = pnl.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                            quantity = tbQuantity.Text; However, it told me that object reference is not set to an instance of an object. Why is it so?

Comment: Exactly!That is the place I would put the for loop.

Comment: @Gwen the tbQuantity is not in panel, it is in gridview. Next to `string prodID =  gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();` add this: `var tbQuantity = gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox; if(tbQuantity !- null) quantity = tbQuantity.Text;`

Comment: Oh ya, the textBox is inside the gridview. Thanks alot! It works now. Really really thanks for your extra effort as I am asking extra questions regarding to this thread

Answer (score 0):

get the row index in the RowDataBound event :

```
 protected void gvProduct_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

       if(e.commandName=="select")
       {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int index = e.Row.RowIndex;

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbCheckRow"); 
            int code = Convert.ToInt32(this.gvProduct.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value);

        }
     }

    }
```

Comment: But how I know whether the checkbox column is checked? as In I should move all the codes inside my lbnConfirm_onClick into here?

Comment: i have edited my answer...!! to help u know how to use datakeys to get values

Comment: But at the gvProduct, it told not does not contain a definition of 'gvProduct' and no extension method accepting first argument type which I encountered the same thing using my code above. Also, I don't have button field in grid view so I can't use the command name. It just simply checkbox coulmn

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717175/get-selecteddatakey-in-rowdatabound

Comment: u must select the event RowDatabound from the Gridview properties

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Is it when I mark the checkbox checked, I also need to click on the Select buttonField column?

Comment: It will only fire when you click the Select buttonfield

Comment: Is there any possible ways to do like when I mark the checkbox checked, it straight away get the row index? Because that's what am I trying to do.

Comment: @Gwen , yes you can do. you have make one ajax call.

Comment: @kumarch1 I amended my code as edited portion. However, the error message now was Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I have no idea how to call my gridview which is in my repeater when button is on click.